# Javascript: Canvas Drawing (2 identical files with different results)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So, I'm going through my javascript book right now and there was a little example of canvas drawing. I copied the code out of the book but the canvas stays white.

I then went on to download the author's collection of all the scripts shown in the book and with his code, it surprisingly works.

To me both codes look identical, the only thing that differs is that I use
" " for strings while the author used ' '.

This is my code:

```
function init() {
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove, false);
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let started = false;

    function handleMouseMove(e) {
        let x, y;
        if (e.clientX || e.clientX == 0) {
            x = e.clientX;
            y = e.ClientY;
        }
        if (!started) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(x, y);
            started = true;
        } else {
            context.lineTo(x, y);
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
```

And this is the code of the author:

```
function init() {
    let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove, false);
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    let started = false;
    function handleMouseMove(e) {
        let x, y;
        if (e.clientX
            || e.clientX == 0) {
            x = e.clientX;
            y = e.clientY;
        }
        if (!started) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(x, y);
            started = true;
        } else {
            context.lineTo(x, y);
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
```

Comment: They're not identical, e.g. you have `y = e.ClientY;`, should be `y = e.clientY;`. (lowercase C)

Comment: Oh god, didnt see that at all.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a little problem in the `handleMouseMove` function. You write

```
y = e.ClientY;
```

But `e.ClientY` doesn't exist, it should be:

```
y = e.clientY;
```